# How do I suppress individual cell values in an MDX query?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I've got an MDX query that's returning 2 different values, a total number of lookups and a number of lookups failed (and some other stuff, but that's the important part).

```
    with
    member [Pct Success] as 'iif(isempty([Num Lookup]) or [Num Lookup]=0, null, 
        100 * (coalesceempty([Num Lookup] - [Num Failed], 0) / [Num Lookup]))'
select
    {
        [Measures].[Pct Success],
        [Measures].[Num Lookup],
        [Measures].[Num Failed]
    } on 0,
[Calendar].[Date].children on 1
from
    [Cube]
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to get another success measurement, but I want this one to suppress any [Num Failed] cells that are below a specific threshold.  Specifically, if I have at least 4 successful lookups (Num Lookup - Num Failed > 3 && Num Lookup > 4), then I want to make that cell's [Num Failed] = 0 (or rather I want to make a copy of [Num Failed] = 0 since I still need to display the original % Success measure).

The underlying facts look like this (just the pertinent subset of columns - the Line column is there for ease of reference, it's not in the actual facts):

```
 Line | CalendarKey | Num Failed | Num Lookup
 1    | 20130601    | 2          | 8
 2    | 20130601    | 5          | 8
 3    | 20130601    | 1          | 8
 4    | 20130601    | 0          | 7
 5    | 20130601    | 7          | 8
 6    | 20130602    | 2          | 6
 7    | 20130602    | 1          | 7
 8    | 20130602    | 5          | 10
 9    | 20130602    | 7          | 9
 etc.
```

What I expect to see for results based on those facts above is:

```
         | % Success | % Filt Success | Num Filt Failed | Num Failed | Num Lookup

20130601 | 61.53     | 69.23          | 12              | 15         | 39

20130602 | 53.13     | 71.88          | 9               | 15         | 32
```

In the above fact sample, lines 1, 3, 4, 7 & 8 all would have a filtered failed value of 0, which gives us the sample output listed above.

My initial thought is to use another member in the with clause as the copy of [Num Failed] and then a Cell Calculation to do the suppression, but I can't get the Cell Calculation to work correctly - it either doesn't modify the value, or it errors out during evaluation.

Here's the non-working version that "should" return what I'm looking for, but doesn't:

```
with
    member [Measures].[Num Threshold Failure] AS [Num Failed]
    Cell Calculation [Data Filter] For '[Measures].[Num Threshold Failure]' AS 'NULL', Condition = 'CalculationPassValue((([Measures].[Num Lookup] - [Measures].[Num Failure]) < 4) AND ([Measures].[Num Lookup] > 4), 1)'
    member [Pct Success] as 'iif(isempty([Num Lookup]) or [Num Lookup]=0, null, 100 * (coalesceempty([Num Lookup] - [Num Failed], 0) / [Num Lookup]))'
    member [Pct Filtered Success] as 'iif(isempty([Num Lookup]) or [Num Lookup]=0, null, 100 * (coalesceempty([Num Lookup] - [Num Threshold Failure], 0) / [Num Lookup]))'
select
    {
        [Measures].[Pct Success],
        [Measures].[Pct Filtered Success],
        [Measures].[Num Threshold Failure],
        [Measures].[Num Failed],
        [Measures].[Num Lookup]
    } on 0,
    { [Calendar].[Date].children } on 1
from
    [Cube]
```

Comment: Post your working with the calculated member please? Sounds like it should work, using another calculated member, probably something minor somewhere :)

Comment: @Meff Added in a non-working query that shows what I think I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not understand your question in every detail, but as far as I understand it, the following should answer it, or at least come close:

```
with
member [Pct Success] as iif([Measures].[Num Lookup]=0,
       null, 
       100 * (coalesceempty([Measures].[Num Lookup] -[Measures]. [Num Failed], 0) / [Measures].[Num Lookup]))
member [Filtered Failed] as iif([Measures].[Num Lookup] - [Measures].[Num Failed] > 3 and [Measures].[Num Lookup] > 4),
        0,
        [Measures].[Num Failed])
member [Bottom Filtered failed] as Sum(Leaves(),
       iif([Measures].[Num Lookup] - [Measures].[Num Failed] > 3 and [Measures].[Num Lookup] > 4),
        0,
        [Measures].[Num Failed]))
member [Pct Filtered Success] as iif([Measures].[Num Lookup]=0,
       null, 
       100 * (coalesceempty([Measures].[Num Lookup] -[Measures]. [Filtered Failed], 0) / [Measures].[Num Lookup]))
select
    {
        [Measures].[Pct Success],
        [Measures].[Num Lookup],
        [Measures].[Num Failed],
        [Measures].[Num Filtered Failed],
        [Measures].[Bottom Filtered Failed],
        [Measures].[Pct Filtered Success]
    } on 0,
    [Calendar].[Date].children on 1
from [Cube]
```

BTW: You do not need to include member definitions in the WITH clause in single quotes unless you aim for the SQL Server 2000 dialect of MDX.
And, according to this [blog post of the former lead developer of the MDX processor](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2005/06/30/how-to-check-if-cell-is-empty-in-mdx.aspx), you can simplify the check for empty and null to just checking for zero.

**EDIT:**

As you stated that users want to use several different tolerances in what-if analyses, what you could do if your cube is not huge, and the number of different tolerances is just a handful, you could pre-calculate the what-if cases, thus making use of the fast response times of Analysis Services for aggregated values.

To do this, you would proceed as follows: build a small dimension table , say dim_tolerance, containing e. g. the numbers 0 to 10, or the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, and 12, or whatever makes sense. Then build a new fact table referencing the same dimensions as the current one, plus the new one, and fill it with the single measure [num failed filtered] calculated as the dim_tolerance value dictates. You could then remove the [num failed] measure from the main fact table (as it would be the same as [num failed filtered] with tolerance 0). Make the attribute in the new dimension non-aggregateable with a default value of 0.

Comment: @FrankPI That doesn't do what I expect it to.  I think the IIF is only checking those conditionals after the rollup happens, so it's never going to take (in my case, I'm rolling up pretty large amounts of data, so my [Num Failed] averages around 30k for any given day.

Comment: OK, in that case the best solution would be to implement `Filtered Failed` as physical measure. You could e. g. build a named calculation in the data source view, and then base the measure on that. Implementing calculations on base data and then aggregating is possible, but slow in Analysis Services.

Comment: That's going to be a problem in that the data consumers want to be able to do what-if analysis on the filtered version and change the threshold.  How slow are we looking at?  Can we pre-calculate some of those fields?  A couple of the MDX queries that I need to do this on are powering async reports, so 30-60 seconds of run time isn't a huge issue.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a `[Bottom filtered failed]` measure. Would that deliver what you need?

Comment: Adding the [Bottom] member into the query changed it from a second or two query to it running for at least 15 minutes and chewing up like 40+GB of RAM on the server (before I cancelled it).  I don't think that's going to work.

Comment: Analysis Services is not optimized for leave level calculations done at runtime. I edited my answer, proposing an approach to pre-caculate the what-if analyses.

Comment: @FrankPI Thanks for the help. It looks like I'm going to have to go down the path of building in another dimension, since I don't have a guaranteed unique dimensional tuple that would uniquely identify each fact in my Measures.